# C# Move files inside dialog's path

Tags: c#, browser, path

I'm struggling with this basic operation.It will be nice if someone can write a working code.So let's say I got folder "AB" on desktop.Folder AB contains subfolder A and subfolder B.Subfolder A contains A.txt and Subfolder B contains B.txt.I want the user to simply choose folder AB via a browser dialog(I did that already) and then,when he clicks on a checkbox,file A.txt will go on subfolder B and B.txt will go on subfolder A.

Comment: I think you can refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc148994.aspx to get all your answer.

Comment: You want to copy the files or move the files??

Comment: @MohitShrivastava He wants us to write a code so that he can swap those files. i.e. copy contents of **A** to **B** and **B** to **A**.

Comment: You can do it by first getting reference of all the files in **A** and **B** then doing move operation.

Comment: @Prajwal You are absolutely correct. But, Since OP is new here we can assist them to write a better question and ask him question for better understandability. I am more surprise that it got a upvote too.

Comment: @MohitShrivastava ha ha. Anyway, I posted an answer. Please check it out. I think that should solve his issues.

Answer (score 2):

I will do this for simple folders **A** and **B**. You will have to consider the chances of sub-folders as well.

```
string[] filesA = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(AsourcePath);
string[] filesB = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(BsourcePath);
foreach (string s in filesA)
{
     System.IO.File.Move(s, AsourcePath);
}
foreach (string s in filesB)
{
     System.IO.File.Move(s, BsourcePath);
}
```

**Please Note:** You will have consider so many scenarios for this including sub-folders, overwriting, existing files or folders etc.

Comment: A work around for his scenario could be just rename the folder **A** with **B** and **B** with **A**. +1 for the effort you have done.

Comment: @MohitShrivastava :D Yea. I never thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the folder path for both A and B folders,

```
 var Afolder = @"D:\AB\A";
 var Bfolder = @"D:\AB\B";
 SwapFolderFiles(Afolder, Bfolder);
```

Pass the folder path for both A and B to SwapFolderFiles,

```
 private static void SwapFolderFiles(string AFolder, string BFolder)
    {

        var AFolderfiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(AFolder);
        var BFolderfiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(BFolder);

        MoveFiles(AFolder, BFolder, AFolderfiles);
        MoveFiles(BFolder, AFolder, BFolderfiles);            
    }

    private static void MoveFiles(string sourceFolder, string destinationFolder, string[] folderfiles)
    {
        foreach (var file in folderfiles)
        {
            var filename = file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf("\\")+1);
            var source = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourceFolder, filename);
            var destination = System.IO.Path.Combine(destinationFolder, filename);
            System.IO.File.Move(source, destination);
        }
    }
```